# How to set date in dataframe for all the lines using TIMESTAMP value available in one of the rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have my data in this format:

```
23:11:16 xyz
23:14:30 xyz
23:26:15 TIMESTAMP 3/23/2020
23:32:31 xyz
0:00:26  xyz
0:00:30  xyz
0:00:55  TIMESTAMP 3/24/2020
0:01:30  xyz
```

and I want to convert it to this format:

```
3/23/2020 23:11:16 xyz
3/23/2020 23:14:30 xyz
3/23/2020 23:26:15 TIMESTAMP 3/23/2020
3/23/2020 23:32:31 xyz
3/24/2020 0:00:26  xyz
3/24/2020 0:00:30  xyz
3/24/2020 0:00:55  TIMESTAMP 3/24/2020
3/24/2020 0:01:30  xyz
```

I am beginner in coding any help would really be appreciated.

as of now I have made it work using this code :

```
#get index for all values with Timestamp
s=account[account['Other'].str.contains('TIMESTAMP', na=False)].index

#assign the date for those indexes
account.loc[s, 'Date'] = account.Other.str.split('\s+').str[2]

#fetch the first date from indexing
a = account.loc[s[0], 'Date']

#iterate thru rows to populate the date
for row in account.itertuples():
    if pd.isnull(account.at[row.Index, 'Date']):
        account.at[row.Index, 'Date'] = a
    elif pd.notnull(account.at[row.Index, 'Date']):
        a = account.at[row.Index, 'Date']
```

*this is just a snippet of code*

The issue with this code is that this does not take in to consideration the change in day and keeps on populating date until the next 'TIMESTAMP' is observed